# Maximum of $\int_0^xF(\xi)d\xi$ with given mean and variance

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Denote $\mathscr{F}$ as all cdf of non-negative RV with fixed mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, I want to know the exact value
$$
\sup_{F\in\mathscr{F}}\int_0^x F(\xi)d\xi
$$
for any $x>0$. I tried several concentration inequalities but they cannot give exact bound or even wrong direction. Could it be exactly evaluated?

Comment: Hint: the set $\mathcal F$ is a convex subset of the convex hull of the point-mass measures on $\mathbb R^+$.  Your desired $F$ is an extreme point of $\mathcal F$.

Comment: @kimchilover Can you explain a little bit? It seems too advanced for me...

Comment: I have posted an answer, but am afraid it might not please you.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathcal G$ be the set of cdfs of non-negative random variables with finite second moments. Define $$A=\left\{\left(\int_0^x F(t)\,dt, \int_0^\infty t\,dF(t), \int_0^\infty t^2\,dF(t)\right): F\in\mathcal G \right\}\subseteq\mathbb R^3.$$
You want to find the maximal $a$ such that $(a,\mu,\mu^2+\sigma^2)\in A$.
In fact, $A$ is the closed convex hull of the set of points obtained by restricting the $F$ to be cdfs of form $F(t)=\chi_{[u,\infty)}(t)$, corresponding to a degenerate random variable which is equal to the constant $u$ with probability $1$. 
For such $F$, the triple $ \left(\int_0^x F(t)\,dt, \int_0^\infty t\,dF(t), \int_0^\infty t^2\,dF(t)\right)$ evaluates to $((x-u)_+,u,u^2)$, where $(x-u)_+$ means $x-u$ if $x\ge u$ and means $0$ if $x<u$.  That is, $A$ is the closed convex hull of the set 
$$E=\left\{ (x-u)_+,u,u^2): u\ge0\right\};$$ 
the extreme points of $A$ are all contained in $E$.
 A result of [Dubins](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82142234.pdf) shows that the extreme points of the set of all points in $A$ of form $(a,\mu,\mu^2+\sigma^2)$ are all convex combinations of at most $3$ extreme points of $A$, that is, of three elements of $E$.

So your $a$ can be obtained by maximizing $$p(x-u)_+q(x-v)_++r(x-w)_+$$ subject to the inequality constraints $$
p\ge0,q\ge0,r\ge0\\u,v,w\ge0$$ and the  equality constraints $$p+q+r=1\\pu+qv+rw=\mu\\pu^2+qv^2+r^2=\mu^2+\sigma^2.$$

This looks to me to be a doable but unpleasant calculus exercise; I have not done it myself.